# How do I display several images using URLs saved in phpmyAdmin in a website?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, web

**See** [Table of report data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1TgE.png)

The table is as displayed in the image above. I wanted to display all the data including several images for which URLs are saved in the `imageURL` column separated with a semicolon.
The number of **image URLs** differs in each columns.

The URLs refer to **image path** in upload folder as shown below:

```
InvestigatorsReportApi/uploads/KBC589L-1.jpg;
InvestigatorsReportApi/uploads/KBC589L-2.jpg;
InvestigatorsReportApi/uploads/KBC 589L-3.jpg;
```

How would I display this in a website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simmply make a query about the URL:

```
$sql = "SELECT url FROM table";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

After that echo it into the `<img>` tag src attribute:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<img src='".$row["url"]."'>";
}
```

And there you have it. The sample code above will print every image in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
$sql = "SELECT url FROM table";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    foreach(explode(';',$row["url"]) as $image) {
        echo "<img src='".$image."'>";
    }
}
```

Comment: just approve answer if this help you

Comment: I cant i have less than 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

First fix your table. It is bad. You should let the attributes occupy the first row:
id: name: LOA: regNO: rout..., then

Answer (score 0):

first you need to use explode function for separate your image url

```
 $image=explode(";",$imageURL);
```

then use foreach loop for display image

```
foreach($image as $value)
{
    <img src='".$value."'/>
}
```